# Jira REST Java Client get all issues using searchJql

Tags: java, jira, jql, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to get all issues from the project using JQL query but get only 50, I know that it is a problem, but how I can figure out with it?

```
Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromiseTest = client.getSearchClient().searchJql("project = UARECR ");
for (Issue issue : searchJqlPromiseTest.claim().getIssues()) {
    System.out.println(issue.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function, which accepts 4 params:

[Jira rest API searchRestClient.searchJql](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client-parent/2.0.0-m8/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/api/SearchRestClient.html#searchJql(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Integer,%20java.lang.Integer,%20java.lang.String))

Now you can set the maxResults value. Since you are not setting it, it is defaulting to 50

Answer (score 0):

searchJql (in v 5.2.5) has this signature:

```
searchJql(String jql, Integer maxResults, Integer startAt, Set<String> fields)
```

If `maxResults` is null, a default value is assumed which seems to be 50. If `maxResults` is specified, it still possible that the Jira instance is configured to never return more then a predefined number of results.

This means that you need to examine the value `SearchResult.total` and repeatedly execute `searchJql` while bumping up `startAt`.